# Error 1017 when extending SimpleButton class in Flash/AS3

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, actionscript, compiler-errors

I am receiving the following compile time error when attempting to extend the SimpleButton class in AS3:

1017: the definition of base class SimpleButton was not found

and the code:

```
package com.shakti.gameState{

import flash.display.SimpleButton.SimpleButton;

public class buttonTile extends SimpleButton {

    public var id:int;
    public var quizId:int;
    public var subjectId:int;
    public var points:int;
    public var questionTxt:String;
    public var order:int;
    public var option:Array;

    public function buttonTile(newId:int, newQuizId:int, newSubId:int, newPoints:int, qtxt:String, newOrder:int, newOption:Array) {
        this.id=newId;
        this.quizId=newQuizId;
        this.subjectId=newSubId;
        this.points=newPoints;
        this.questionTxt=qtxt;
        this.order=newOrder;
        this.option=newOption;
    }
}}
```

This is an action script 3 file being developed in Flash.

Thanks for your help!
Kevin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Import the class.

```
 import flash.display.SimpleButton
```

I get this all the time from copy and paste:)